# Oracle SQL into SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas

Hi Im trying to adapt a Proc Sql into SAS Enterprise Guide, Im having some trouble with the OVER / PARTITION BY function. Im getting a syntax error message, could someone guide me with this one? Is it possible to run this on SAS?

```
proc sql;
         create table NACIONAL as
           select distinct AÑO,
                            MES,
                             TABLA_ORIGEN,
                                Sum(Sum(flag)) OVER ( partition BY AÑO 
                                    ORDER BY MES rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS siniestros_total 
                    FROM   (SELECT NRO_SINIESTRO, 
                                   MES, 
                                   AÑO, 
                                   CASE 
                                     WHEN Extract(month FROM MES) = Min (Extract(month FROM MES) 
                                          OVER (partition BY NRO_SINIESTRO, Extract(year FROM AÑO)) 
                                        THEN 1 
                                     ELSE 0 
                                   END                               AS flag 
                            FROM   work.Universe2 
                            GROUP  BY AÑO, MES, NRO_SINIESTRO) AS dt 

      QUIT;

NOTE 137-205: Line generated by the invoked macro "FRECUENCIAPAGOS".
311         TABLA_ORIGEN;       QUIT;             proc sql;              create table NACIONAL as                select distinct
311      ! AÑO,                        MES,                            TABLA_ORIGEN,          Sum(Sum(flag)) OVER ( partition BY AÑO
                                                                                                             ____
                                                                                                             22
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.  

NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "FRECUENCIAPAGOS".
311         TABLA_ORIGEN;       QUIT;             proc sql;              create table NACIONAL as                select distinct
311      ! AÑO,                        MES,                            TABLA_ORIGEN,          Sum(Sum(flag)) OVER ( partition BY AÑO
                                                                                                             ____
                                                                                                             76
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

```js
OUTPUT DATA   
   
Año   Mes Tabla_Origen siniestros_total
2013 1 A1               1
2013 3 A1               2
2013 5 A1               2
2013 6 A1               3
2013 8 A1               4
2014 1 A1               1
2014 4 A1               2
2014 5 A1               3
2014 6 A1               4
2013 2 A2               1
2013 4 A2               2
2013 6 A2               3
2014 9 A2               1
2014 12 A2               2
```

```html
INPUT DATA    
    
Año   Mes Nro_Siniestro Fecha_Pago Tabla_Origen
2013 1 1234         01/1/2013 A1
2013 3 1235         01/3/2013 A1
2013 5 1235         01/5/2013 A1
2013 6 1236         01/6/2013 A1
2013 8 1237         01/8/2013 A1
2014 1 1238         01/1/2014 A1
2014 4 1235         01/4/2014 A1
2014 5 1236         01/5/2014 A1
2014 6 1239         01/6/2014 A1
2013 2 1233         01/2/2013 A2
2013 4 1235         01/4/2013 A2
2013 6 1236         01/6/2013 A2
2014 9 1240         01/9/2014 A2
2014 12 1241         01/12/2014 A2
```

The column siniestros_total should perform a cummulative count distinct by month and should restart each year.

Comment: You cannot use those statements in PROC SQL.  Can you explain what the query is doing, with sample input and output records?  Then someone can suggest how to do it in SAS code.  Note that SAS will automatically remerge detail records with group by statistics. So if you just want to have the group sum() copied onto each detail row then just ask for it.  For example try:  `select *,mean(age) as gender_mean_age from sashelp.class group by sex`

Comment: If you have direct access to your server you can use SQL Pass through, which passes the SQL commands to the server. Otherwise, Oracle SQL is not the same as SAS SQL, and your code will need to be modified to work in SAS.

Comment: @Tom, I have updated my question with input and output data, please let me know if something isnt clear, thanks for taking some time to help me out.

Comment: This specific type of code cannot be run directly in SAS. It will need to be converted to SAS SQL. `sum over` is not valid in this type of SQL. It can be done, but you'll need to change the syntax slightly.

Comment: Thanks @StuSztukowski, is there any way you could guide me in some way? Im a novice user with SAS, used the program so far with in built modules but its my firts time with the code.

Comment: In order to better assist you, can you give us a basic walkthrough of what you are trying to accomplish with the dataset?